# Enable API key only for some functions from yml

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

```
Function_Name:
  handler: function path
  events:
    - http:
        path: path/{id}
        method: get
```

I want to add apikey required for that function, how should I do? I don't want to make it manually from aws.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless Framework has option to add `apiKeys` under `provider` section at `serverless.yml`. Find example code below for your reference.

```
service: demo-api-key
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  apiKeys:
    - "demo-apikey"
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
  message:
    handler: private.message
    events:
      - http:
          path: message
          method: get
          private: true
```

or else checkout this [plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-add-api-key) for alternative way.